# Container Engine Websockets Bottleneck

Tags: websocket, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a KnowHow Question. I hope this is ok.

I have a Container Engine from Google, running 3 instances of Docker Containers. I have a Load Balancer Service in front. The Websockets from the FrontEnd connect to that Services.

Now my question is. Is this LoadBalancer a Bottleneck? Or are the websockets somehow connected directly to the actual docker instances?

If it is a Bottleneck, is there someway around it?

Answer (score 0):

**From my limited knowledge and assumptions, no intimate Google knowledge implied**

This somewhat depends on the load balancer's implementation. As you can expect, there is some variety of load balancing techniques.

Load balancers are designed to act as low-level packet filters and shouldn't create a bottle-neck.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)#Load_balancer_features) has some interesting info, as well as [this "white paper"](https://f5.com/resources/white-papers/load-balancing-101-nuts-and-bolts) and [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756878(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_nlb_how_fenf).

However, some software load balancers are actually more similar to Proxy servers. In these situations, all websocket connections (and Http connections) are connected to the load balancer and it could become a bottleneck...

I'm assuming that Google didn't botch the job on the load balancer and that they are using low-level architecture (packet handling) rather than TCP/IP connection proxy style forwarding.

In any case, you should be aware that websocket connections that connect to different Docker instances can't communicate with each other unless you bridge them together.